# How to add dynamic outer apply in SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-apply

I have a task.

Basically I am selecting from table.

I want to outer apply (which means execute some code for each row) based on dynamic number coming form different table.

In Other words, I want to have dynamic number of outer apply.

Example :

```
SELECT  C.ClientName, CS.Cnt
FROM Client C


OUTER APPLY
(
   SELECT  count(*) AS Cnt  from ClientStatementDetail 
   where A= 1 AND B = 2
  AND ClientdId = C.CLientID
) AS CS

-- I want to add another Oute Apply with diffrent condition.

OUTER APPLY
(
   SELECT  count(*) AS Cnt2  from ClientStatementDetail 
   where A= 3 AND B = 9
  AND ClientdId = C.CLientID
) AS CS2

-- Now my problem that I do not how many combination Of A and B I have. 
-- They are coming form diffrent table
```

Onthing came to my mind is to create a table value function that will return for me a table for all the rows

for that client then select the result. However in order to do so, we have to crate  structure table with dayanmic columns.

In Other words, I was trying to implement this :

[Dynamically add 50 columns to table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245326/dynamically-add-50-columns-to-table-variable)

But structure tables can not be accessed in table function.

Any Help is appericated.

Comment: Is there any reason at all where creating a table-valued function would work better for you than a few queries? In any case, the only way I can think to return dynamic columns without dynamic sql is to create all columns and then selectively drop them with IF (and maybe a loop)

Comment: Are you expecting a separate count for each OUTER APPLY or the sum of all of them?  In your example you have both OUTER APPLYs aliased as CS, wasn't sure if that was intentional.

Comment: @GeorgeDando I am expecting different one.

Comment: Any particular query will always produce a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their names and their data types. You *cannot* write a query with a variable number of columns. Dynamic SQL is a way of *writing new queries* which is, of course, how they can achieve various different outputs (because you construct different queries), but as noted, you *cannot* use dynamic SQL in a table-valued function.

Comment: You'll probably need to end up with an output containing just 3 columns - `A`, `B` and `Cnt` and then do any pivotting of that data (so moving each count into a separate column) outside of SQL, in whatever report builder/application is consuming your result set.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am using simple console application in .Net

Comment: Yes, and you can write C# code that can pivot a result and produce an unbounded number of "columns". You cannot do that in T-SQL.

Comment: I was thinking so, however I wanted to do all the work in the database layer and leave the service layer thin.